# Backbone.js with Twitter Bootstrap TypeAhead

Tags: backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

There is an [anonymous gist](https://gist.github.com/1745614/) which goes through how to get twitter bootstrap's typeahead working with backbone.js.  How would I implement this in practise?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "implement this in practise"?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I am to enter options into `this.$el.typeaheadBackbone()` to get it going or how exactly I get it working.